# PySide packaging error (macholib) python setup.py py2app

Tags: python, qt, packaging, pyside, py2app

I am quite new to Python and PySide and trying to package a very simplified test case into an standalone app OS X. I put the test on github https://github.com/eerne/pyside-py2app-test

- Python 2.6.1 that is shipped with OS X 10.6.7
- Qt 4.7.3 from http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/qt-for-open-source-cpp-development-on-mac-os-x
- PySide 1.02 from http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/PySide_Binaries_MacOSX

The test just opens a QWebView() and loads test.html, this runs fine with `python test.py` but when trying to package with `python setup.py py2app` it errors:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/macholib/MachO.py", line 180, in load
raise ValueError("Unknown load command: %d" % (cmd_load.cmd,))
ValueError: Unknown load command: 34
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/macholib/MachO.py(180)load()
-> raise ValueError("Unknown load command: %d" % (cmd_load.cmd,))
```

Interestingly it builds an app in dist/test.app which does run on my machine, but not on others. Here the complete log http://pastie.org/1891942

I am clueless if it is a pyside related issue, Qt or something I'm missing setup.py

Other tests that do not include PySide package fine, without errors. So I assume this is either Qt or PySide related.

At this point I'm looking for any pointers or suggestions to which mailing-lists I could ask.

Comment: One more thing: I'm using the binaries and not built PySide nor Qt from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to upgrade [macholib](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/macholib).  That load command (0x22) is defined in the version [here](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/macholib/src/7dedc813f36c/macholib/mach_o.py), which is the dev version.

Comment: Hi thouis I got to the next step after `easy_install macholib==dev` (is this the recommended way of installing it?). Then after another error I upgraded modulegraph with `easy_install modulegraph`. Now when packaging this is the newest error `NameError: global name 'chain' is not defined` see full log http://pastie.org/1893135

Comment: btw I also tried `easy_install modulegraph==dev` but that had a lower version number and didn't seem to make any difference, so I went back to just `easy_install modulegraph`

Comment: Finally got it!! It seems `from itertools import chain` is missing in build_app.py (located at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python/py2app/`) see comment by Christopher Barker http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2010-July/022491.html

Comment: Kind of bad to modify a file under `System/Library/`. Others must have run into the same issue, wondering now what the better approach is to fix it. I'm too scared to screw things up, but next time I'll try `easy_install py2app` first.

Comment: I agree.  I usually work in a virtualenv with --no-site-packages for just these sorts of reasons.